# Current date in constructor

Tags: java

I have a class `Sale`, which looks like this

```
public class Sale extends Transaction
{
    //Attributes
    private static AtomicLong newSaleId = new AtomicLong();
    /**
     * The date of sale
     */
    private Date saleDate;
    /**
     * The sale id;
     */
    private long saleId;

    //Constructor

    Sale()
    {
        saleId = newSaleId.incrementAndGet();
        saleDate = 
    }
}
```

Constructor is not finished. Does anyone know how to set current date every time a new object is created? Thanks.

Comment: what about `saleDate = new Date()`?

Comment: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/current-date-time-in-java/

Comment: You could also consider using `LocalDate`. i.e. `LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();` (or `LocalDateTime` if you need the time too).

Answer (score 1):

To set the current date, just instantiate a new `Date` object:
`saleDate = new Date()`

See this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()) for the `Date()` constructor for an explanation.

I will also encourage you to explore the new [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) classes introduced in Java 8, and here's an article explaining why they are better: [Java 8 Date and Time API](http://javahash.com/java-8-time-and-date-what-has-changed-for-better/)

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know it's so simple.